# Is there any limit on number of fields we can create in a single table in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

To my understanding, if CnosDB stores data using a key-value model and treats all fields as values, there would be a problem where the efficiency decreases as the number of fields increases. I am not sure if my speculation is correct, but I have not found any information regarding the limit on the number of fields in CnosDB's documentation.